# How to tell the gdb the value of the 'optimized out value' or make it infer the value?

Tags: gdb

There is a C++ `this` pointer that is an `<optimized out>` value, but up the call stack its value can be found.

How to tell gdb that `this` has that specific value? Can gdb look at the stack and infer it?

Comment: Can you compile without optimizations?

Comment: @ks1322, yes, I can recompile without optimizations, but that's not the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this in gdb, at least not in the form of having `print this` know which frame to inspect to find the value.

One simple work around is to use a convenience variable.  For example something like:

```
(gdb) up 5
(gdb) set $mythis = this
(gdb) down 5
(gdb) print *$mythis
```

Another approach would be to write a "convenience function" (that's the term used in the gdb manual) to automate this.  Convenience functions are written in Python and can do many things, such as look for symbols in other stack frames.  So, for example, you could write a `$_this` function and use it like:

```
(gdb) print *$_this()
```

... not quite the same but maybe it would fit your needs.